# Ackermann Function (4, 1) in C Not Calculating - Ackermann with Caching

Tags: c

After using high-level languages for a while to get work done (MATLAB, R) I've recently become quite interested in C, and am using it to try and understand the interaction between software and hardware a little better.
I wrote out quite a simple recursive function to compute Ackermann:

```
int ackermann(int m, int n)
{
    if (m == 0)
    {
        return n + 1;
    }

    if (m > 0 && n == 0)
    {
        return ackermann((m - 1), 1);
    }

    if (m > 0 && n > 0)
    {
        return ackermann((m - 1), ackermann(m, (n - 1)));
    }
}
```

(with a loop for `m` and `n` in `main`, of course) which works for values up to (4, 1). I know this is quite a large value and it is not feasible to calculate beyond this. I added some print statements to my driver loop to figure out what is happening:

```
 for (int m = 0; m < 5; m++)
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < (6 - m); n++)
        {
            printf("\nCalculating Ackermann of (%d, %d)...\n", m, n);
            printf("Ackermann(%d, %d) = %d \n", m, n, ackermann(m, n));
        }
    }
```

It sits at `Calculating Ackermann of (4, 1)...` for around 5 seconds or so and then the program stops. It doesn't seem to be gobbling up memory although I can't say for sure that it isn't running out of resources.

I went to find a solution and stumbled upon this code on a website named RosettaCode.com. The author states that it caches some known values to allow some larger values to be calculated.

Quite audacious, but could anybody explain what this is doing? I have seen the left bit-shift `<<` before, I'm aware that `malloc` is for dynamic memory allocation (so I assume this is handling the array of pre-cached variables?) but the `storage_bits` have just completely baffled me (I'm interested in, but not familiar with this low-level stuff).

```
// Ackermann function with caching - Understand how the bit-shift works?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int m_storageBits = 0;
int n_storageBits = 0;
int *valCache;

long int ackFunc(int m, int n)
{
    int cacheIndex = 0;
    int ackResult  = 0;

    if(!m)
    {
        return (n + 1);
    }
    if (n >= 1 << n_storageBits)
    {
        printf("%d, %d\n", m, n);
        cacheIndex = 0;
    } else {
        cacheIndex = (m << n_storageBits) + n;
        if (valCache[cacheIndex])
        {
            return valCache[cacheIndex];
        }
    }

    if (!n)
    {
        ackResult = ackFunc((m - 1), 1);
    } else {
        ackResult = ackFunc((m - 1), ackFunc(m, n - 1));
    }

    if (cacheIndex)
    {
        valCache[cacheIndex] = ackResult;
        return ackResult;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int m = 0;
    int n = 0;

    // Specify value size that may be saved
    m_storageBits = 3;
    m_storageBits = 20;   // 2**20, ~1 megabyte

    valCache = malloc(sizeof(int) * (1 << (m_storageBits + n_storageBits)));
        printf("\nValue cache before memset: %i", valCache);
    memset(valCache, 0, sizeof(int) * (1 << (m_storageBits + n_storageBits)));
        printf("\nValue cache after memset: %i", valCache);

    for (m = 0; m <= 4; m++)
    {
        for (n = 0; n <= 6 - m; n++)
        {
            printf("\nCalculating Ackermann of (%d, %d)...\n", m, n);
            printf("Ackermann(%d, %d) = %d\n", m, n, ackFunc(m, n));
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see I added some print statements around the `memset` but the values appear the same. I tried a few different formats but I'm honestly not sure how, or even if, I can output this properly. I've changed some of the syntax and replaced the completely unhelpful one- or three-character variable names with some more useful descriptors based on what I can understand from the code.

As I said, quite bold to ask someone to comb this and explain it to me but I am stumped. If not, I'd be **happy just understanding why my simplified approach conks out at ack(4, 1)** (which is quite demanding but I have a fairly modern ThinkPad).

Thanks! Help appreciated.

Comment: Your version runs out of memory not because the numbers get big - that would just overflow the integers and produce the wrong numbers.  Why it runs out of memory is because C does not have tail recursion so every time a function is called a new stack frame is added to the stack.  But there is a maximum size allocated to stack and when you overflow that by making a million function calls you write over important stuff and everything crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As I said, quite bold to ask someone to comb this and explain it to me but I am stumped. If not, I'd be happy just understanding why my simplified approach conks out at ack(4, 1) (which is quite demanding but I have a fairly modern ThinkPad).

I’ll use Python to illustrate, because it has a built-in dict type.

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(16392)

cache = {}


def ackermann(m, n):
    if m == 0:
        return (n + 1, 1)

    if (m, n) in cache:
        return cache[(m, n)]

    if n == 0:
        r = cache[(m, n)] = ackermann(m - 1, 1)
        return r

    r1, e1 = ackermann(m, n - 1)
    r2, e2 = ackermann(m - 1, r1)
    r = cache[(m, n)] = (r2, e1 + e2)
    return r


print(ackermann(4, 1))
```

The code is a bit of a mess – simplifying with `functools.lru_cache` runs afoul of the C stack on my platform – but the important thing is that it evaluates A(4, 1) *and* keeps track of how many calls to `ackermann` it would have produced without the cache.

> (65533, 1431459240)

1,431,459,240 is a lot of calls, even for a fairly modern ThinkPad.

As for the C code: it’s doing the same thing, keeping a mapping of (m, n) to A(m, n) to avoid the blowup in number of calls, but because C doesn’t have a built-in hash table, it keeps things simple by using one big block of memory as a two-dimensional array, where each index’s least significant `n_storageBits` bits represent n and the rest represent m. That’s what the bit shifting does.

- A(4, 1) is evaluated
- (4, 1) is converted to an index in such a way that every supported (M, N) pair produces a distinct result, in this case with 2<sup>b</sup> M + N with b chosen such that N < 2<sup>b</sup> for any supported N
- The index is used to look up and store the result in an array with size 2<sup>b</sup> M + N + 1 for the maximum supported M.

Comment: The C code is accessing and allocating the array quite wrong; it needs to make a 2^nbits * 2^mbits array; it makes a 2^nbits + 2^mbits, so randomly tromps on memory....

Comment: @mevets: It makes 2^(nbits + mbits) = 2^nbits \* 2^mbits.

Comment: sorry, you are right, but where it indexes into it by m<<n_storageBits, it needs to be bound m by 1 << m_storageBits.

Comment: @mevets: True, but it has the excuse that it will never finish computing nor produce a correct result for m ≥ 6 – the function grows too quickly :)